# Connecting a Pressure Sensor and LCD to an Arduino

Tags: arduino, sensors, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, lcd

I was working on a project that involved the connection of a digital pressure sensor with a LCD and Arduino board.

The LCD model is 1602 16x2 Character LCD Display Module HD44780 Controller Blue/Green screen blacklight LCD1602 LCD monitor 1602 5V.

The Arduino Board I am using is Arduino UNO R3 Compatible Atmega328P Board.

These are the details of the pressure sensor:
Company Name: Mouser Electronics
Mouser P/N: 785-SSCDRRN005PD2A3
Description: DIP, Dual Rad Barbed Honeywell Board Mount Pressure Sensor, Digital Output, I2C transmission, address 0x28, pressure +5psi to -5psi

Can anyone help me with the code for this project specifically the pressure sensor? I can't understand how to write the code for getting digital outputs?

I tried using the following website as well for the code for the pressure sensor but it doesn't work for some reason. I kept the connections and the code the same as on the website:
https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/HoneywellTruStabilitySSC-HSCPressureSensors

The code for the pressure sensor is as follows:

```
#include <Wire.h>

#include <SSC.h>



//  create an SSC sensor with I2C address 0x78 and power pin 8.

SSC ssc(0x78, 8);



void setup() 

{

  Serial.begin(115200);

  Wire.begin();



  //  set min / max reading and pressure, see datasheet for the values for your sensor

  ssc.setMinRaw(0);

  ssc.setMaxRaw(16383);

  ssc.setMinPressure(0.0);

  ssc.setMaxPressure(1.6);



  //  start the sensor

  Serial.print("start()\t\t");

  Serial.println(ssc.start());

}



void loop() 

{

  //  update pressure / temperature

  Serial.print("update()\t");

  Serial.println(ssc.update());



  // print pressure

  Serial.print("pressure()\t");

  Serial.println(ssc.pressure());



  // print temperature

  Serial.print("temperature()\t");

  Serial.println(ssc.temperature());



  delay(5000);

}
```

The Serial monitor just prints start() and then update() but no subsequent readings for the code and connections on the website.

If someone could write out the code I would be highly grateful. Thank you!

Comment: Please add the code you currently have. Makes it a lot easier for us to help.

Comment: Additionally to Markus' comment:  "doesn't work for some reason" is not helpful enough. If necessary, add test output ( Serial.print  ) and report that log.